# Linux command not very clear

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Can you please help me out within this point:

```
F1=${F2%%.(out*|txt|zip)}
```

I don't know what's this command stands for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably nothing natural https://explainshell.com, You can try to ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/
But for sure, they will need more clues, and avoid to cross domain posts, if you will put it there, then delete the question there, please.

Answer (score 2):

That shell variable assignment would likely do nothing at all.

One part of this assignment with which you may be unfamiliar is the `%%`.  From `man sh` on my system, a quick search reveals:

```
 ${parameter%%word}
     Remove Largest Suffix Pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a
     pattern.  The parameter expansion then results in parameter, with
     the largest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.
```

What you *may* be looking for is the following:

```sh
shopt -s extglob

F1="${F2%%.?(out*|txt|zip)}"
           ^
           note the difference
```

The `extglob` shell option exists in **[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)**, and allows you to use bash's "extended glob" format, including the `?(pattern)`. Try a `man bash` and search for `extglob` for details.

Note that you haven't tagged your question with `bash`, just `sh`. There is no `extglob` in POSIX shell, and the the notation of your assignment has no special meaning in POSIX.  The equivalent functionality in POSIX shell would require a loop through the extensions you're trying to remove.